# JavaFX how I Can Get value form TableView to textfield

Tags: javafx

Someone help me, How I can pass a value from TableView(TableView show data from database) to textField and then the same value save to database??

Regards
ps I can Show the source code;

I think I m not able to explain it,  I show u piece of code
this is my 1 st fxml file where I take data from user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mojprogram.elkosz.controllers.AddCashRegisterController">
   <children>
      <GridPane prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="624.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="295.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="193.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="449.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="407.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label text="Model Kasy Fiskalnej" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Numer Seryjny" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label text="Data Zakupu" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label text="Data Pierwszego Przeglądu" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <Button fx:id="choisebutton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#choiceCompany" text="Firma" />
            <Label text="Data Następnego Przeglądu" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <TextField fx:id="companytextfieldCH" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="cashMachinetextfield" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="serialnumber" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <DatePicker fx:id="buydate" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <DatePicker fx:id="firstcheck" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <DatePicker fx:id="nextchech" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Button fx:id="addmachine" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addCashRegister" text="Dodaj" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

This is Controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


import java.io.IOException;


public class AddCashRegisterController {
    @FXML
    private Button addRegister;
    @FXML
    private TextField cashMachinetextfield;
    @FXML
    private TextField serialnumber;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker buydate;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker firstcheck;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker nextcheck;
    @FXML
    private TextField companytextfieldCH;

    private CashRegisterModel cashRegisterModel;
 public void choiceCompany() {
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ChoiceCompany.fxml"));
        try {
            Parent parent = loader.load();
            ChoiceCompanyController controller = loader.getController();

            Scene  scene = new Scene(parent);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

            stage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 @FXML
    private void initialize(){

        this.cashRegisterModel = new CashRegisterModel();
 }


    public void addCashRegister() {
    }
}
```

This is fxml file with Tableview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:id="choiceCompany" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="487.0" prefWidth="743.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mojprogram.elkosz.controllers.ChoiceCompanyController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="CompanyTableView" onMouseClicked="#choice" prefHeight="446.0" prefWidth="743.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="companycolumn" prefWidth="120.0" text="Nazwa Firmy" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="NIPcolumn" prefWidth="116.0" text="NIP" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="citycolumn" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="115.0" text="Miejscowość" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="streetcolum" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="113.0" text="Ulica" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="contactcolumn" prefWidth="124.0" text="Osoba Kontaktowa" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="phonecolumn" prefWidth="153.0" text="Numer Telefonu" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="closeButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeButtonaction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Ok" />
         </children>
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets />
         </opaqueInsets>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets right="35.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

This is controller of this

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import mojprogram.elkosz.modelFX.CompanyFx;
import mojprogram.elkosz.modelFX.CompanyListModel;
import org.omg.CORBA.portable.ApplicationException;

import java.awt.*;


public class ChoiceCompanyController {
   @FXML
    public Button closeButton;

    public VBox getChoiceCompany() {
        return choiceCompany;
    }

    @FXML
    private VBox choiceCompany;
    @FXML
    private TableView<CompanyFx> CompanyTableView;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CompanyFx, String> companycolumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CompanyFx, String> NIPcolumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CompanyFx, String> citycolumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CompanyFx, String> streetcolum;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CompanyFx, String> contactcolumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CompanyFx, String> phonecolumn;

    private CompanyListModel companyListModel;



    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        this.companyListModel = new CompanyListModel();
        try {
            this.companyListModel.iniati();
        } catch (ApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.CompanyTableView.setItems(this.companyListModel.getCompanyFxObservableList());
        this.companycolumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().companyNameFxProperty());
        this.NIPcolumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().NIPfxProperty());
        this.citycolumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().cityfxProperty());
        this.streetcolum.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().streetfxProperty());
        this.contactcolumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().contactpersonfxProperty());
        phonecolumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().phonenumberfxProperty());

    }
    @FXML
    public void choice() {

        //CompanyTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        CompanyFx selected = CompanyTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        System.out.print(selected.toString());
    }

    @FXML
    public void closeButtonaction() {
        Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

From this tableview I try to pass value to textfield and then I want to save it in new table of database

Comment: Explain what you mean by "pass a value from `TableView`". A `TableView` is backed by a list of objects. What do you mean here?

Comment: Not sure, but sounds like @DGRay wants to edit a `TableView`'s field and update his database after the update. Just a guess.

Comment: I using ObjectProperty to fill this tableview, user can pick one row(I need take one value from one column but I think I need take Object coz I want to make foreign key in new database table) and value from this table transfer to TextField and this textfield value  save to new table in database I hope u get it

Comment: Please don't edit your post to remove your code when you get an answer.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: @Makyen they vandalized it again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understant what you need exactly ,but i think that you desire to get value from row of TableView and pass value of cell to TextField, you can do this if you acces to rows and get values from cells one by one.

```
        PersonView.setRowFactory(event -> {
        TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();

        row.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            try {

                if (row.isSelected) {

                    if (row.getItem().getId() != null && row.getItem().getName() != null) {
                     String Id=row.getItem.getId();
                     String Name=row.getItem.getId();
                     IdTextField.setText(Id);                        
                     NameTextField.setText(Name);
                    }


        });
        return row;
    });
```

I hope this code can help you